Reaction Collector not collecting reactions in DMs
I am using Discordjs v14.15.3. The following script is supposed to send an invitation via DM to all members who have opted into our coffee chats to confirm that they are interested in participating this week. It should then listen for a reaction to that invitation and respond accordingly.
The invitation is sent out correctly, and I receive it in my DMs. 'Collector Created' is logged to the console, but when I react to the message, the bot does not respond. The current implementation uses no filter for the collector, but that failed to solve the problem. I have been stuck on this for weeks so any help would be immensely appreciated.
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const { Database } = require('djsbotbuilder');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions
    ],
    partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction, Partials.User]
});

module.exports = {
    interval: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // Interval in milliseconds (1 week)
    execute: async (client) => {
        const coffeeChatters = await Database.CoffeeChat.findAll({ where: { OptedIn: true } });

        for (const chatter of coffeeChatters) {
            
            const serverRecord = await Database.Server.findOne({ where: { id: chatter.ServerId } });
            if (!serverRecord) {
                console.error(`Server record not found for ServerId: ${chatter.ServerId}`);
                continue;
            }

            const memberRecord = await Database.Member.findOne({ where: { id: chatter.MemberId } });
            if (!memberRecord) {
                console.error(`Member record not found for MemberId: ${chatter.MemberId}`);
                continue;
            }

            const server = await client.guilds.fetch(serverRecord.ServerId).catch(err => {
                console.error(`Failed to fetch server with ServerId: ${serverRecord.ServerId}`, err);
                return null;
            });
            if (!server) continue;

            const member = await server.members.fetch(memberRecord.MemberId).catch(err => {
                console.error(`Failed to fetch member with MemberId: ${memberRecord.MemberId}`, err);
                return null;
            });
            if (!member) continue;

            const message = await member.send('Would you like to participate in this week\'s coffee chat? React with  for "yes" or  for "no".');

            // Add reaction options to the message
            await message.react('');
            await message.react('');

            // Update the member's record with the message ID
            await Database.CoffeeChat.update(
                { InvitationMessageId: message.id },
                { where: { MemberId: memberRecord.id } }
            );

            // Create a reaction collector
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                console.log(`Reaction: ${reaction.emoji.name}, User: ${user.tag}`);
                return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name);
            };

            const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ time: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }); // 1 week in milliseconds

            console.log('Collector created.');

            collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
                console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);

                try {
                    // Check if the reaction is on an invitation message
                    const memberRecord = await Database.CoffeeChat.findOne({ where: { MemberId: user.id, InvitationMessageId: reaction.message.id } });
                    if (memberRecord && memberRecord.OptedIn) {
                        let response;
                        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            response = true;
                        } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                            response = false;
                        }

                        // Update the database with the user's response
                        await Database.CoffeeChat.update(
                            { OptedIn: response },
                            { where: { InvitationMessageId: reaction.message.id } }
                        );

                    } else {
                        console.log(`No member record found for user: ${user.tag} with message ID: ${reaction.message.id}`);
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error handling reaction:', error);
                }
            });

            collector.on('end', collected => {
                console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} reactions`);
            });
        }

        // Collect responses and match members
        // This part requires additional implementation to handle responses and matching
    },
};

I found this post which could potentially be related as I am also using fs to keep my code organized into multiple files, however, per the suggestion in that post, I am already using readdirSync.
